# Python - complex questionaire with CLIPS

Tags: python, decision-tree, clips, pyclips

I have a rather large questionaire on my page right now with around 50 questions whose purpose is to see if the user could be a relevant client of mine. I want to reduce it to 5 or max 10 questions by only asking relevant questions at each step and generating a new question based on what he replied in the previous questions (not only the last one). I have a graph of how I want the questions to be connected and I also have some pseudo code in CLIPS which basically does this really well.
The problem is, that the only python package (PyCLIPS) which can load CLIPS I found is running only on Python 2.5 and hasn't been updated for few years, so CLIPS is not a very good option right now.

I have seen one other question here about similiar stuff ( [What libraries for modeling complex questionaire in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362034/what-libraries-for-modeling-complex-questionaire-in-python) ) but the answer there is to use automata which is not really good for me because I will have also numerical answers and logical combinations of other previous answers.

Is there some other package which does something similiar or some other way how to connect CLIPS (or other expert system) to python?

Comment: Which version of python are you targeting? PyCLIPS runs on newer versions of python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407474/installing-pyclips-based-on-clips-6-30-for-windows-python-2-7-32-bit

Comment: Gary - PyCLIPS doesn't run under Python 3.